# Cannot assign destructured props to react-bootstrap component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I have installed [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) and want to customize default buttons for my project so that I can simply write `<Button>` without any `variant` option for most buttons.

```
import * as bs from "react-bootstrap";

export const Button: bs.Button = ({
  variant = "outline-secondary",
  ...props
}) => {
  return <bs.Button variant={variant} {...props} />;
};
```

This results the following error.

> TypeScript error in /path/to/MyComponent.tsx(11,11):
> Type '{ variant: string; } & Pick<PropsWithChildren<ReplaceProps<As, BsPrefixProps & ButtonProps>>, "slot" | ... 262 more ... | Exclude<...>>' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<ComponentPropsWithRef, Exclude<keyof ComponentPropsWithRef, "slot" | ... 262 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture">> & BsPrefixProps<...> & ButtonProps & { ...; }'.
> Type '{ variant: string; } & Pick<PropsWithChildren<ReplaceProps<As, BsPrefixProps & ButtonProps>>, "slot" | ... 262 more ... | Exclude<...>>' is not assignable to type 'Pick<ComponentPropsWithRef, Exclude<keyof ComponentPropsWithRef, "slot" | "style" | "title" | "as" | "bsPrefix" | ... 258 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture">>'.  TS2322

If I wrote without destructuring it works somwhow.

```
export const Button: bs.Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <bs.Button {...props} variant={props.variant || "outline-secondary"} />
  );
};
```

Why does the first one not work? What dropped from the `props`?

**Update**
versions: TypeScript 4.0.2, React 16.13.1, React Bootstrap 1.3.0

Comment: As you spread that way, your `...props` would be come `Pick<PropsWithChildren<ReplaceProps ...>` which  `PropsWithChildren...` is the react-boostrap calculation whichis quite complex. I think it contains issue now. So to hack this you just simply specify the type for your props. Then it would work `bs.ButtonProps`

Comment: @tmhao2005 You have a point. I generally don't like to say that something is not my error but tool's one, however, your comment really makes sense since TS infers a complex type `React.PropsWithChildren<ReplaceProps<As, BsPrefixProps<As> & bs.ButtonProps>>` from the original argument without destructuring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are almost there.

Your code doesn't work because you aren't declaring the type of props, so you just need to do:

```js
const ButtonX: bs.Button = ({
  variant = "outline-secondary",
  ...props
// Here´s the secret - a set props as bootstrap ButtonProps type
}: bs.ButtonProps) => {
  return <bs.Button variant={variant} {...props} />;
};
```